# Proving the completeness of a theory $\Gamma$

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

Given a set of sentences $\Gamma$ in a first-order-language $\mathcal{L}$, such that for all structures $\mathcal{A}=(A,\ldots)$ and $\mathcal{B}=(B,\ldots)$, if both $\mathcal{A}$ and ${\cal B}$ realize $\Gamma$, and $A$ and $B$ are at most countable sets, then $\cal A\cong \cal B$.

I have to prove that $\Gamma$ is complete.
Should I now assume that, for a given $\cal L$-sentence $\varphi$, *not* $\Gamma\models\varphi$, and derive that $\Gamma\models \neg\varphi$ must hold? I have tried this, but I don't have a clue how to do it.

I've also tried considering two random structures $\cal A,\cal B$ that realize $\Gamma$, but from there I can't derive anything.

Is one of these approaches right, or do I have to try something else?

Comment: Is $\cong$ elementary equivalence?

Comment: No, it means isomorphic

Comment: x @konewka, Okay, that is an even stronger assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\Gamma\models\varphi$ iff $\mathcal{A}\models\varphi$ for all $\mathcal{A}$ which realizes $\Gamma$. $\Gamma$ has just one (at most) countable model. If $\Gamma$ has infinite model and if $\mathcal{A}$ is an uncountable model of $\Gamma$, you can find a countable one which is elementary equivalent to $\mathcal{A}$.

---

If $\mathcal{L}$ can be uncountable, we can construct a counterexample of the problem.

Consider the language consists of constant symbols $a$, $b$ and $c_r$ for each real number $r$. Let $\Gamma$ be the set of formulas which consists of the formulas
$$a=b\leftrightarrow c_r=c_s \qquad \text{for each }r\neq s$$

and

$$a=b\leftrightarrow \forall x\forall y (x=y).$$

If $\mathcal{A}\models \Gamma$ and $a^\mathcal{A}=b^\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{A}$ has just single element, and if $\mathcal{A}\models \Gamma$ and $a^\mathcal{A}\neq b^\mathcal{A}$ then $\mathcal{A}$ must be uncountable. So every model of $\Gamma$ which is at most countable is isomorphic, but $\Gamma$ is not complete since neither $a=b$ nor $a\neq b$ is derived from $\Gamma$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand. Can I now say: let $\cal A$ be a countable model of $\Gamma$, and let $\varphi\in\cal L$. Then either $\cal A\models\varphi$ or $\cal A\models\neg\phi$ so $\Gamma\models\varphi$ or $\Gamma\models\neg\varphi$?

Comment: @konewka If $\Gamma\not\models\varphi$, then there is a model $\mathcal{A}$ of $\Gamma$ such that $\mathcal{A}\models \lnot\varphi$. However, you can prove that every model $\mathcal{B}$ of $\Gamma$ is elementary equivalent to $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: And how exactly should I see that all uncountable models are elementary equivalent to a countable one? Is that a theorem and should I read my book better or does it follow from the premises (it doesn't, right?)

Comment: @konewka If your language is countable, then you can apply *downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem*. Consider the set of sentence which is true over $\mathcal{A}$. (That is, consider $\operatorname{Th}\mathcal{A}=\{\sigma:\mathcal{A}\models\sigma\}$. Since it has a model (namely $\mathcal{A}$) you can countable one which satisfies $\operatorname{Th}\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: My language $\cal L$ isn't necessarily countable, and as I commented on the other answer, I haven't yet encountered the LS theorems (only briefly in another course), so I'm afraid I can't apply them here. Is there another way?

Comment: @konewka I think if we allow $\mathcal{L}$ can be uncountable, then there is a counterexample of this problem. I'll suggest it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\Gamma$ is *not* complete. Then there is a $\varphi$ such that $\Gamma,\varphi$ and $\Gamma,\neg\varphi$ are both consistent. By Gödel both have models, and then by the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem each has an at most countable model. These models are in particular models of $\Gamma$ ...

Comment: I have briefly encountered the Löwenheim-Skolem theorems in another course, but in this course they have yet to be explained. Is there a way to prove it without LS?

Comment: @konewka: If you carefully trace what happens in the proof of the completeness theorem, you'll find that it actually proves directly that a consistent theory with countable vocabulary has an at most countable model. The appeal to Löwenheim-Skolem is just because that bonus information is not typically included in the _statement_ of the completeness theorem.